# GET request method in PHP

Tags: php

Looking at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html there are 8 'valid' request methods: `OPTIONS`, `GET`, `HEAD`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `TRACE`, and `CONNECT`.

The variable, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` seems to be the one that has the information needed but after a quick search on the web, it looks like that variable could contain just about any value.

So, should I default any unknown values to a `GET` method or should I serve an `error/404`?

Is there a more robust way of getting the request method in php?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to serve is up to you. There is not really a wrong or right (i.e. serving a GET instead of the requested method). Although following RFCs / spec is usually nice to do so.

Just imagine the HTTP PATCH method (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789). It's not in your list yet! So what do you want to happen when someone starts to request it while you haven't supported it?

I would serve a 405 status code as an error, since you do not support the method.

Afaik there is not a more robust way to get the request method.